# How to fix error "Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified."

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Hello i get this error after i run docker-compose build up

But i get this error
postgres_1 | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.

Here is a snap shot of the error!
[image]

And down below is my docker-compose.yml file

version: '3.6'

## Server.js file

```
services: 
  smart-brain-api:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./
    command: npm start
    working_dir: /usr/src/smart-brain-api
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/smart-brain-api
 
  #PostGres Database
 
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: *Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.* This indicate you have to create a db with correct credentials

Comment: POSTGRES_PASSWORD can be put in an .env file in the same directory as the docker-compose.yml file. The .env file could look like this: `POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password`. The docker-compose.yml file could look like this: `POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}`.

Comment: I downloaded postgres image and have the same error, but I don't have any `docker-compose.yml` nor `Dockerfile` on my desktop. Where to put the `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"`? And is my assumption that the postgres runs inside that container right or is there a problem that the host system should run it?

Comment: Other answers cover the solutions mentioned here, but this CircleCI forum post provides some additional context as well as which versions are affected: [PostgreSQL Image Password Not Specified Issue](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/postgresql-image-password-not-specified-issue/34555)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To avoid that you can specify the followings environments variables for postgres container on your docker-compose file.

**POSTGRES_PASSWORD**
This environment variable is normally required for you to use the PostgreSQL image. This environment variable sets the superuser password for PostgreSQL. The default superuser is defined by the POSTGRES_USER environment variable.

**POSTGRES_DB**
This optional environment variable can be used to define a different name for the default database that is created when the image is first started. If it is not specified, then the value of POSTGRES_USER will be used.

For more information about Environment Variables check:
https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: How to achieve the same without a docker compose file, for example through `docker run` command?

Comment: use the arg -e to sets environments vars.

Answer (score 55):

You can use the `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD` environment property by making the following change to your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "db"
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
```

The above will solve the error.

Comment: But it's unsafe method as the Postgres pay attention: "...This is *not* recommended."

Answer (score 33):

It's already mentioned in the interactive mode; how to run the container, if you don't find it, use the following:

To allow all connections without a password use:

- docker run -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres:9.6 (use the tag you need).

To specify postgres password for the superuser, use:

- docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<your_password> postgres:9.6 (use the tag you need).

Comment: Postgres explicitly states allowing all connections without a password is not recommended.

Answer (score 7):

Summing up the command on official docker site:

```
docker run --name <YOUR_POSTGRES_DB> -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<YOUR_POSTGRES_PASSWORD> -d postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make change to your docker-compose.yml file like in example:

```
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
```

Comment: Postgres explicitly states this is *not* recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can make your connection using the below docker command:

`docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<your_password> postgres:9.6`

Comment: This is the same as the 2nd solution in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64112321/2227743)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The yml language is space sensitive so `POSTGRES_DB=postgres` is different to `POSTGRES_DB = postgres`

Comment: Hi, your answer contains a right content, but it's not applicable here. The question already has an accepted answer. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you