# docker-compose: postgres_1 | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'
services:
    postgres:
        image: 'postgres:latest'
    redis:
        image: 'redis:latest'
    nginx:
        restart: always
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
            context: ./nginx
        ports:
            - '3050:80'
    api:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
            context: ./server
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./server:/app
        environment: 
            - REDIS_HOST=redis
            - REDIS_PORT=6379
            - PGUSER=postgres
            - PGHOST=postgres
            - PGDATABASE=postgres
            - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
            - PGPORT=5432
    client:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
            context: ./client
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./client:/app
    worker:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
            context: ./worker
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./worker:/app
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build`, everything works fine apart from postgres, which provides me with the error below. I've tried applying the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420940/how-to-fix-error-error-database-is-uninitialized-and-superuser-password-is-not) but the error message won't go away; not sure what I'm missing here.

```
postgres_1  | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
postgres_1  |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
postgres_1  |        superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
postgres_1  |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  |        See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
postgres_1  |        https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

I've got this `keys` file inside of my `server` folder, which I think was used on the course I'm following to provide the `environment` parameters of the `api` in the `docker-compose` file:

```
module.exports = {
    redisHost: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    redisPort: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    pgUser: process.env.PGUSER,
    pgHost: process.env.PGHOST,
    pgDatabase: process.env.PGDATABASE,
    pgPassword: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
    pgPort: process.env.PGPORT,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres), the postgres image *needs* the environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to be set.

Something like this:

```
postgres:
  image: 'postgres:latest'
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
```

There's not much more to it. You can try to create a docker-compose.yml with just that code and see if it starts correctly with `docker compose up` (it should).

If it still doesn't there might be something wrong with the cached `postgres:latest` image.
Might wanna try a `docker image rm postgres` and then calling the docker compose command again.

Warning: make sure you didn't have important data in the db before doing that.

Comment: for future reference: my confusion was adding the `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` to the `api` environment, and not creating an `environment` for `postgres` in the dockerfile