# kubectl database service crashing postgres?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to configure the database deployment for postgres for kubernetes.. But I keep getting the following error. Can someone advise me what I could be doing wrong?

database/secret.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-secrets
type: Opaque
data:
  database: ZXRs
  username: cG9zdGdyZXM=
  password: cG9zdGdyZXM=

database/deployment.yml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgresdb
          image: postgres
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-secrets
                  key: database
            - name: DATABASE_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-secrets
                  key: username
            - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-secrets
                  key: password
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgresdb
            - name: postgres-secrets
              mountPath: "/etc/postgres-secrets"
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: postgresdb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
        - name: postgres-secrets
          secret:
            secretName: postgres-secrets
```

Logs

```
   kubectl logs postgres-6667fcb9c-sk77f
```

Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

```
   You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
   connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.

   See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

Comment: You've named your environment variables `DATABASE_PASSWORD` and similarly, but as per the error message they need to be `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`.  The only thing you need to change is the `env: [{ name: }]`s; the structure of the Secret can stay as is.

Comment: As per David maze Comment, you need to use the environment variable as `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` and in conjunction  with this you need to use user_name as `POSTGRES_USER` and have a try . Refer to this [docker official document](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) and stack case on [How to fix error "Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60420940/) by john for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.

1. The environment variables used in the deployment YAML are incorrect. Check the secret definition YAML below to know the correct names to be used for postgres variables
2. The secret file is not needed to be mounted as volume inside the pod

Update database/secret.yml as shown below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: postgres-secrets
type: Opaque
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: ZXRs
  POSTGRES_USER: cG9zdGdyZXM=
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: cG9zdGdyZXM=
```

Update database/deployment.yml as given below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgresdb
          image: postgres
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: postgres-secrets
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgresdb
      volumes:
        - name: postgresdb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pvc
```